# How to Download Video from Online and store it local Device then play video on Flutter apps Using video player?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, video-player, flutter-web

I want to develop a flutter application where users can download all Videos from Online by one single button and store it local Device then play those videos offline on Flutter apps Using video player?

I did this by assets video. But if I use video from assets and build the application then the apk size will bigger. That's why I want to make this flutter application where users open the app and click one single button by button on pressed the list videos downloaded from the predefined server via a link in selected widgets. Then users can play those videos via video player.

Answer (score 12):

You might wanna give a try to the [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package it is an http client that supports file downloading and save it locally to a given path.

Here's a code sample (source: [iampawan's Github](https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterDownloadFilesWithProgress/blob/master/lib/main.dart))

```dart
Future downloadFile(String url) async {
  Dio dio = Dio();

  try {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    await dio.download(url, "${dir.path}/myFile.txt", onProgress: (rec, total) {
      print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print("Download completed");
}
```

Comment: side note, u need path_provider package to use that getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()  function https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Comment: if i want to store it in the app storage not in the device , what should the solution be ?