# how to download https network URL images into app directory in flutter

Tags: flutter, https, dart-pub

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:image_picker_saver/image_picker_saver.dart';

```
try {
  var response = await http.get(imageURL); // problem is here (only working on http URL)

  debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());

  var filePath = await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(
      fileData: response.bodyBytes);

  var savedFile= File.fromUri(Uri.file(filePath));

  print('Image path: $savedFile');

 /* setState(() {
    _imageFile = Future<File>.sync(() => savedFile);
  });*/

} on PlatformException catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks similar to this: [How to Download Video from Online and store it local Device then play video on Flutter apps Using video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948686/how-to-download-video-from-online-and-store-it-local-device-then-play-video-on-f/59965108#59965108)

Here's the answer I've given at the time:

You might wanna give a try to the [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package it is an http client that supports file downloading and save it locally to a given path.

Here's a code sample (source: [iampawan's Github](https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterDownloadFilesWithProgress/blob/master/lib/main.dart))

```dart
Future downloadFile(String url) async {
  Dio dio = Dio();

  try {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    await dio.download(url, "${dir.path}/myFile.txt", onProgress: (rec, total) {
      print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print("Download completed");
}
```

You will also need [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) tu use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`.